# Rails where(id: [1, 2, 3]) query how to get the id that failed the search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am querying Users like so `User.where(id: [1, 2, 3]` to get a result of three Users with the ids 1, 2, and 3.

If for example User with the id 3 was deleted from the db the previous query would only get two results, User with id 1 and 2.

This is fine for small amounts of ids however a problem for a large array.

I want to know if there is a way to find which one of the ids failed and didn't show up in the results. Is there a method to identify which one of the results failed?

Comment: Is `ids = [ 1,2,3]; missing_ids = ids - User.where(id: ids).ids` efficient enough for you? It could build a very large `Array` not to mention a very large sql statement depending on the size of `ids`

Comment: I think it could work. How would you do it for a `User.find([1,2,3])` because it throws an exception @engineersmnky

Comment: That means none of them exist [See Here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) Thus the `where` method is better

Comment: So given `[2,3,5,6,11,23,42]` and users with ids `2`, `3`, and `23`, you'd want to get `[5,6,11,42]` back? Which database and how big is this array going to be? Is the array really an arbitrary array or is it really a range? Does the array come from somewhere inside the database or is it just built in your app?

Comment: The database is postgres, array may only be a few numbers to a hundred. Ids will be inputed by the user in the frontend and will be arbitrary. @muistooshort

Comment: @engineersmnky's solution should be fine for a hundred elements. For larger arrays you could start looking at SQL solutions that are variations on `select dt.id from users u right join unnest(array[1,2,3,4,5]) as dt(id) on u.id = dt.id where u.id is null`, `select dt.id from users u right join (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)) as dt(id) on u.id = dt.id where u.id is null`, or a temp table instead of inlined arrays or VALUES expressions.

Comment: @muistooshort that is why I asked. Also you implementation is now database dependent e.g. MSSQL does not support `unnest(array[])` syntax to my knowledge

Comment: @engineersmnky And that's why I asked about the database. Besides, database independence is incredibly difficult if you want to use the database as more than a glorified spreadsheet. Once you get past baby-talk SQL (i.e. `select * from table where a = b` and the like) then portability goes out the window, just adding a GROUP BY clause can throw out portability.